# Gratis portable PDF to MS Word converter for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, document-converter, portable

The title says it all ^

I don't care if it is command line only or has a GUI. I don't need batch capabilities, and am willing to open a PDF editor and "File/Save as ..".

I just want something that can one-off convert a 30 page PDF to as close as possible to MS Word format, even if I end up having to manually update some stuff, such as heading levels.

There are no images in this document, if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are several on-line choices. The one I use for most of my PDF-related needs has a bunch of conversion/joining functions, each with its own URL. Of those, the one relevant to your question is [PDF to DOCX](https://pdf2docx.com/). Depending on your standards/expectations and the complexity of your document, this does a pretty good job.

As I mentioned, there are other choices, but I like this one because (at least as of this writing) it is free of charge without being overly aggressive with ads, and it doesn't require registration. (At least one of its "free" competitors throws up a modal dialog leading to who knows how many survey questions/ads before letting you download the resulting file(s).)

Comment: Thanks. I will check that out, although I would really strongly prefer a Windows app

Comment: As you alluded to in your question, some PDF "editors" probably have an export-to-Word function. I was actually looking for a PDF editor for other purposes, and kind of got lost in the weeds while using the search term "pdf editor" on this site; it's impressive how many related questions there are. There might be competent Word-exporting options already mentioned in one of those.

Comment: Good idea; I will take a look. Thanksk (+1)

Comment: If you find a good one, don't hesitate to self-answer here!

Answer (score 1):

Hope [Simpo PDF to Word Portable](https://www.thinstallsoft.com/files/1567/) could satisfy all the requirenments